# How to handle taxes as NRI doing remote job abroad

Tags: taxes, india, non-resident, software

I am a software developer living abroad (NRI) and intend to transition into remote freelance consulting. I am anticipating an annual income surpassing 60 Lakh INR. My plan is just to visit India for a few weeks annually for holidays. I have a few queries and would appreciate some clarification on the matter:

- What are my tax liabilities in India?
- Can I receive this income directly into my NRE bank account?
- And is it necessary to establish a registered entity for this endeavour?
- I'm curious about the process of invoicing my European clients.